# Unable to change language at login

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, login

I cannot login because I cannot type English.
I have tried many shortcuts other suggested but none of them helped me.
I also tried recovery mode but I cannot type English even there and cannot do anything.
Could you help me?

Comment: There were two languages, Japanese and Russian. I deleted Japanese although my keyboard layout is Japanese and logged out. And I got this problem. So there is only one language and I can see it at the top right corner.

Comment: When we use Japanese one, we can type both by switching by a special key(called Zenkaku). So I thought there is such key even in Russian keyboard, found and tried it. But it didn't work.

Comment: I tried that. But I cannot type "startx" ...

Comment: I could open console but couldn't type them

Comment: It is Russian. I could type in only Russian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround:

1. logon to live session of Ubuntu.. (I have used Ubuntu 18.04 bootable USB)
2. mount your root partition with below command (change sda5 with your root partition number)
   `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt`
3. open the file `/mnt/etc/default/keyboard` with below command
   `sudo -H gedit /mnt/etc/default/keyboard`
4. The content in this file should look like similar to below, even if its not just make the content same like below.

Here: us=English us, jp=japanese, ru=russian. you can remove "us" if you dont want

```
XKBLAYOUT=us,jp,ru
BACKSPACE=guess
XKBVARIANT=,
```

5. Save the file, Close.
6. unmount the partition /dev/sda5 with below command
   `sudo umount /mnt`
7. reboot to see all the 3 languages at login screen..

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved the problem!!!
I want to vote but I cannot beacause I don't have enough reputations. Sorry.
Anyway you explanation is so easy to undderstand and helped me:)