# Ubuntu 18.04 can't change language at login screen

Tags: keyboard, login, language-support

I have accidentaly remove removed English language from 'Regional settings and languages' and now I cannot change my language to EN at the login screen. I have tried activating Screen Keyboard and there is a 'Regional Settings' button, but it doesn't open the settings, just closes the screen keyboard.

Also, I have tried entering the password using ASCII codes (ALT+number code to get a desired letter), but this doesn't work at login screen.
Is there any way force login screen to use English language for keyboard?

I am running Ubuntu on VM if this matters. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1135022/739431. try this. if you can access "Advanced Options" at grub menu.. then logon to root shell and do the changes.. no need of liveusb..

Comment: @PRATAP I have managed to enter the root shell from "Advanced Options", but root shell also start without EN language and I cant do anything without it. Now I am going to try to boot from a recovery USB. Looks like that's my only option.

Comment: yup you r rite..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to change language at login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134992/unable-to-change-language-at-login)