# Why does my lockscreen still use UK layout despite I've set my input to be US specifically? Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: keyboard, input-method

Since, I've (@) used in my password. I've to use (shift + ") to get '@' while on lockscreeen whereas as I'm logged in I've to use (shift + 2) for '@' which is fair.

Comment: Hi..what is your 0S? Do you have two languages set? Are you sure you are not talking about login screen?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Yes , Shift + 2 doesn't work for inserting (@) into my password but works when I'm logged in.

Comment: Do you hv two languages set? Can you lock your screen with super+l shortcut n then type the pw?

Comment: No , I've already removed UK from input and then restarted and tried logging in several times but didn't work out.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134992/unable-to-change-language-at-login

Comment: I've been logging in using (Shift + " ) key to get (@) i.e a UK layout so why isn't lock screen using US layout that I've set to work with.

Comment: `nano /etc/default/keyboard`     What is the output of this command?

Comment: XKBLAYOUT="us"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"

Comment: File is ok.. Just change pw without @ symbol n then make sure it types @ symbol in texteditor then set pw using@ symbol..

Comment: @YuganTej That isn't really solving his problem. The problem is that the lock screen believes he's using a UK keyboard, while his desktop believes he's using a US keyboard. Removing the @ will work for this specific case, but there are quite a few other keys that don't map to the same place on the two keyboards. What's the login manager? gdm? lightdm?

Comment: @Auspex my assumption is that.. 0P might have created the pw with UK layout and assuming he used @ symbol.. What I proposed will ensure OP what's the pw he typed..

Comment: After removing and adding again , the problem has been solved eventually but I don't know what character has been used in the password since I used Shift+2 and idk what's the input my laptop took ! And I'm using Shift+2 to enter that character to login but I can't make sure what's the character being used either @ (US Layout) or " (UK Layout)

Comment: @milan-md79 if you read my comment.. I suggested to type the pw in text editor first.. that makes you sure what pw you typed.. also you can check with on screen keyboard..